# C++, download file in directory

Tags: c++, windows, download, directory

So I have this simple code to download a file from an url opening the browser

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string dwnld_URL = "http://www.url.com/downloadpage";
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", dwnld_URL.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    return 0;
}
```

But I want the file to go in the current directory instead of going in the default download folder. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Use [Windows HTTP Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the more generic [WinINet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how can I know?

Comment: This is why studying computer science and/or information technology several years at some University is worthwhile.

Comment: You are executing shell, so system finds application associated with urls and by default browser is launched and it downloads it content of link. By default web browsers are storing files in download directory. Basically your program just starts external program.

Answer (score 8):

if you're on windows, you can use

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string dwnld_URL = "http://www.url.com/downloadpage/filename.txt";
    string savepath = "C:\\tmp\\filename.txt";
    URLDownloadToFile(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read more about  [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)s first.

You want some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client library; you could consider [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), but both [Qt](http://qt.io/) and [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) have some functions for HTTP client. And probably Windows might have some specific functions around that.

<sup>All three `libcurl`, `Qt`, `POCO` are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) libraries, and can run also on Linux and POSIX systems.</sup>

If you need an HTTP server library (which does not seem the case), you could find some also (e.g. [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), ...)

Regarding your comment (which should have gone into your question) "but how can I know"?, an intuition could be, for remote data access, to focus on protocols.

Whatever library (or framework) you are using, you'll need to spend many hours or days to study it and read its documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Ok I downloaded the libcurl library... now, is there a specific function I should use? I looked up for it but I couldn't find it... I'm really a newbie, so I'm sorry if my questions look obvious...

Comment: `libcurl` has a good tutorial. But you need to understand HTTP before.

Comment: for the sole purpose of moving files around without impacting the system too much there is the [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362708(v=vs.85).aspx) as well